# connect iphone through wifi by programming?

Tags: iphone

I'm implementing a iPhone application in which I want to connect two iPhones through wifi and I want to send some alert messages.

I have done research but not got success.

Can you advice me if is it possible or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you want to connect via peer-to-peer protocol you could have a look to GameKit.
Shall also work for BlueTooth.

If you have the waranty that both devices are connected to same wifi network you should use Bonjour/zero-conf protocol.